# How does S3 avoid url collisions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I noticed that I uploaded a public asset to my S3 bucket and it is accessible via the `https://assets-development.s3.amazonaws.com/foobar.png` URL. I am wondering how S3 avoids collisions URL name.

Am I really the only one that has an S3 bucket named `assets-development`?

Comment: Amazon S3 bucket names are globally unique. Yes, you are the only owner of a bucket with that name.

Comment: Yes. If it allows you to create this bucket with this name, than you are the first one.